# Changing class data type from parent to child in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a parent class let say Foo...

```
class Foo
{
  protected string $value;

  public function __construct(string $value) {
    $this->value = $value;
  }

  // ...OTHER METHOD
}
```

And, the class Foo has been extended by Bar

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
  protected null|string $value = null; // Or equivalent to ?string

  public function __construct(null|string $value = null) {
    $this->value = $value;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this throw error no matter what I do.
I know this can be solve by using `protected mixed $value;` on parent class. But I don't want to do that and want it to be strict as string data, not as mixed data. I also don't want to use `protected null|string $value;` on parent class a and using the same constructor.

To solve this problem I've try a few thing like modified parent:

```
class Foo
{
  protected null|string $value;

  public function __construct(string $value) {
    $this->value = $value;
  }

  // ...OTHER METHOD
}
```

I want to force the parent to only accept string data, if not it will throw exception.
And in child, it can accept null (default) or string.. Other that that will throw exception

Comment: It seems that you already have a solution. What do you want to ask?

Comment: The question, I don't want to use `null|string` or `mixed` or anything rather than `string` type in the parent class, but to use only `string` type on parent class. But the problem is, it's not extendable. Because, using any other type in parent class could lead me to get `null` value by accident while extending the parent class to other class. Since $value on parent class also could also accept any other type such as `null` or anything. Or it's not even possible to do that?

Comment: `I know this can be solve by using protected mixed $value; on parent class. But I don't want to do that`...because?

Comment: If this is possible, that means the derived classes can set $value to null, the derived classes can also call parent's methods, BUT these methods should treat $value non-null. How do you solve this contradiction?

Comment: Why not just have `class Bar extends Foo
{
  protected null|string $value2 = null; // Or equivalent to ?string

  public function __construct(null|string $value = null) {
    $this->value2 = $value;
  }
}` ? And ignore the $value in the parent entirely, if you want to accept different values there?

Comment: `How do you solve this contradiction`...by not letting the derived class accept null values. Why do you need to do that? I think the example in the post is so trivial as to be meaningless, and doesn't give any clue about why you're actually trying to do this, or what practical problem it would solve.

Comment: @ADyson The reason why the OP added the type-hinting 'null' is to set it to null. So this is a dead end.

Comment: @shingo I was asking why they wanted to be able to set it to null in the child class. Especially if they know there are functions in the parent class which require it not to be null. It doesn't appear to make much sense, and no clear justification has been given for the requirement, so it's difficult to see why anyone would need to try and solve it. That was my point.

Comment: `Why not just have class Bar extends Foo.....` Because, from parent class there's a method use to process the data `$value`. By using `$value2`, it's no different than creating new class and copy paste all the method available on parent class.. `or what practical problem it would solve.....` Sometime the parent class could return null value that make me wonder where the problem comes from and spending hour only to find the problem come from the parent class the should not return null value

Comment: `Especially if they know there are functions in the parent class which require it not to be null`,, this give me concrete reason.. And should I change the parent class to accept `null|string` type, while the derive class to only accept `string` type.. I mean to swap the class

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. If that works for you, do it. If you want to ensure that people cannot directly instantiate the parent class and input a null value, declare it as abstract

Comment: `I mean to swap the class`,, this is the same.. I'm having same error as before.. `declare it as abstract`,, I could try it first to see if the `abstract` class resolve the problem

Comment: It occurs to me that because `$value` is `protected`, it cannot be modified outside the class. So you cannot write `$x = new Bar("33");
$x->value = "2";` for example. Therefore, even if you have `protected null|string $value = null;` in the class definition, the only way to set `$value` is through the constructor. So if you put `public function __construct(string $value) {
    $this->value = $value;
  }` in the `Bar` class then no-one can set a null value for this string anyway. Demo: https://3v4l.org/fgOuB - as you can see it crashes trying to create an instance where value is null

Comment: So I think that might solve your problem? Users of the Bar class cannot assign null to the $value, but Foo can still be extended with nullable value if you need it to. Tell me if I'm wrong...I'm still not 100% sure I understand everything you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know anything about your code beyond what you've posted, so please don't take any offense, but if you are using inheritance solely for sharing methods, you might not have the best pattern. For a concrete example, I sometimes see `User extends Database` because people want to say `$this->fetch(...)`. There's several alternatives including traits, interfaces and dependency injection that a lot of people would say is a better pattern in that case.